# Pass the entire global state to 'mapStateToProps'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to pass to the redux connect 'mapStateToProps' function the **entire** global state

The, inside my components i can just access the state which is now the global state.

Is there anything wrong with that?

I don't want to slice the state into many chunks and give it sliced to each component but just give the entire global state.

Are there any performance problems with that ? I understand that it re-renders the entire component but with react's diffing algorithm i imagine it should be fine.

Using a '`this.props.count`' is not as suggestive as doing a '`this.props.todoSection.count`. Just a readability thing.

I read that 'time-slicing api' in react 1.6 could potentially improve the various performance problems related to mantaining a global state.

https://auth0.com/blog/time-slice-suspense-react16/

Comment: can u share your code ?

Comment: No, i think it is self explanatory.  In the connect->mapstatetoprops just pass the entire state as opposed to cherry picking it whatever part of the state you use in the component.

Answer (score 4):

Technically it's possible, but the better practice is to create `mapToStateProps` in each component which using global state. And map the only needed props in it.

Comment: (upvoted; just a suggestion) maybe better to use word `map` instead of `pass` as pass suggests `mapStateToProps` arguments?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Connecting more components is usually better for performance, because each component only needs a smaller piece of the store state, and so most of the time it wont need to re-render.

Answer (score 2):

And then what? whenever something change anywhere in the state, regardless if its related to your component or not your component would rerender?

why would you ever want something like that? (just curious)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think for readability it would be much better to have a global state than to have multiple local states each mapped to a part of the global state. Using a 'this.props.count' is not as suggestive as doing a 'this.props.todoSection.cout. Just a readability thing. Is the performance problem of re-rendering the entire chain component really bad?

Comment: it is really bad for a few reasons two most important of which are: 1) performance (you risk that your app constantly rerenders which will soon end up in usless ui) and 2) you are breaking components encapsultions: you want component to have a single/narrow task and for that you want it to get only data it needs. i see no readability gain at all since its just naming: `this.props.count` > `this.props.todosCount`

Comment: it not renaming 'this.props.count' to 'this.props.todoscount', but to this.props.todoSection.count. Now you know where the 'count' came from exactly without looking at the definition of the connect.

Comment: i mean, if name like `this.props.count` gives you readability issues use something mode descriptive like `this.props.todosCount`

Comment: you know where it came from anyways by looking at `mapStateToProps` in the same component

Comment: I know i can look at the definition, but i dont want to check the definition then memorize it and go back to the markup. It is similar in concept to understand alot of what a function does by looking at its signature in java/c#

Comment: then you have a problem with react/redux. bottomline: you'll pay a very high price for your lazyness ;)

Comment: if you so much dont want to look into `mapStateToProps` then introduce naming convention like `this.props.todoSection$count` or something like that. just dont map the whole state

Comment: yes, performance impact is as high that any decent size app will very soon become literally useless with ui blocking all over the place

Comment: A lot depends on how much of the state is used by each component. Connecting a component does not mean it’s dom will change for changes in state. Yes the reconciliation algorithm will need to be run unnecessarily, but without knowing how large an app you have, it’s hard to say if global state is “bad”.

Comment: thats why i say 'for any decent size app'. on the other hand, breaking some clear rules/patterns with clear reasons why they exist for no real gain is a bad practice in my view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you *don't* want to map the entire global state, just the relevant reducer. So you certainly *could* map just that one store:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ todoStore }) => ({ todoStore });
```

That'd be much less costly than mapping the whole store, but at scale it could start causing performance issues across your app if the store gets big enough (and/or the end-user's browser is crappy enough). At best it's an antipattern.

---

> Using a `this.props.count` is not as suggestive as doing a `this.props.todoStore.count`. Just a readability thing.

You *could* always namespace while still mapping only the data you need:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ todoStore: { count, foo } }) => ({ todoStore: { count, foo } });
```

That'd give you the shape you want while only connecting the state required. But comes with the slight developer cost of repeating the property names - and still requires defining what state to map - which maybe defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'll admit: I _am_ currently doing just that - mapping entire reducers to the state (didn't know any better) - and it's led to some noticable lag on slower devices.